# Action of $S^1$ on homotopy groups of an $S^1$-space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

I am interested in the following question : Let $S^1$ be the $1$-sphere, seen as a topological group by being the unit sphere in the complexe plane $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a (good, ... etc) pointed space with a continuous action from $S^1$. Is the induced action of $S^1$ on its homotopy $\pi_{\ast} (X)$ trivial ?

This is motivated by trying to understand the $S^1$ action on $THH$. It seems like the $S^1$ action is trivial on $THH_{\ast}$ but I don't understand why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. $S^1$ is path connected, so every element of $S^1$ acts by a map homotopic to the identity.

Comment: And note also that $S^1$ can't act reasonably on a discrete group anyway; the automorphism group of a discrete group is also discrete.

Comment: Yeah for sure, I'm the worst at math. Thanks! For your second argument, don't you need the induced action of $S^1$ on the homotopy of $X$ to be continuous again ? I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: @Bogdan: I dunno, it would be pretty weird if it weren't. In any case, for most groups like $\mathbb{Z}$ the automorphism group won't have very many elements that are divisible, but every element of $S^1$ is divisible.

Comment: @Bogdan: but none of this is particularly relevant to the $S^1$ action on THH. This is a higher categorical phenomenon: in general, to give an action of a topological group $G$ on an object in a higher category $C$ means to give a functor $BG \to C$. When $G = S^1$ the classifying space $BS^1 \cong B^2 \mathbb{Z}$ is a homotopy $2$-type and so $C$ needs to be at least a $2$-category for this definition to be interesting, whereupon it turns out that an $S^1$ action on an object $c$ is the same thing as an endomorphism of the identity $\text{id}_c : c \to c$.